# nuke.File_Knob() class isn't setting filenames in other nodes

Tags: python, scripting, nuke

I am using the Script Editor to group a number of nuke nodes together.
I want to reduce the number of inputs using the Knob interface. One of these is to select the image file. So I am using

```
ux_File = nuke.File_Knob("my_file", "Filename")
```

Then I want to use that filename and set it for the DeepRead Nuke Node using

```
nDeepRead = nuke.nodes.DeepRead(file = "parent.my_file")
```

So that anytime the filename is changed (in the Knob interface) it updates the DeepRead node (hidden in the group).
How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer will be the following:

```
fileKnobPath = '/Users/swift/Desktop/file.exr'
nuke.nodes.DeepRead(file=fileKnobPath)

deepRead = nuke.nodes.DeepRead(file="[value DeepRead1.file]")
```

The last command creates new Deep nodes with expression in `file` knob.

[image]

For force reload use this method (in case filename was changed):

```
nodes = nuke.allNodes()

for node in nodes:
    if node.Class() == "DeepRead":
        node.knob("reload").execute()
```